# Mono C# compiler response file syntax

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I have a basic foundation in C#, having used it briefly at a previous job. Right now I'm working on really understanding the language and its paradigms by going through [Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework](http://www.apress.com/9781430242338?gtmf=r). However, my main computing environment is a GNU/Linux system so I'm doing this using Mono.

That said I'm running into a problem using the mono C# compiler (*mcs*) to run a build using a response file (*.rsp*). Where can I find documentation about how mono parses these files and the syntax it expects?

Mostly I've run into not knowing how to specify a comment (the # symbol which is a comment under the Microsoft implementation seems to be interpreted as a file by mcs), and not knowing how to specify the options themselves.

```
# TestApp.rsp
-r:System.Windows.Forms.dll
-target:exe -out:TestApp.exe *.cs
```

When compiled:

```
$ mcs @TestApp.rsp
error CS2001: Source file `#' could not be found
TestApp.rsp(2,0): error CS1024: Wrong preprocessor directive
TestApp.rsp(2,0): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `-'
Compilation failed: 3 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Comment: Looks like changing '-' to '/' and using MS-style options fixes that part of it. But I'm still stumped on comments. I've tried all the usual suspects (`' " ; #`) but none of them are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mcs` doesn't seem to support comments. It just loads the response file line-by-line, strips any single or double quoting and processes the line as if it were passed as a command line argument. You can look at the [LoadArgs function in mcs source](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-4.0.0.121/mcs/mcs/settings.cs#L620). It would be easy to add comments, though, so you might want to submit a patch or pull request.